# qt How to pass a QkeySequence of a qshortcut() to function through connect(Signal,Slot)?

Tags: c++, qt, keyboard-shortcuts, signals-slots, qkeysequence

I'm trying to connect several shortcuts to a slot,in order to get their key value and append it to a variable. Something like text input, so i do something like this:

```
button_1 = new QShortcut::QShortcut(QKeySequence("1"),this);
connect(button_1,SIGNAL(activated(QKeySequence)),this, SLOT(keybord_shortcuts(QKeySequence)));
```

which is not correct because `activated()` wont get the sequence that calls the shortcut to my slot `keybord_shortcuts`.

```
No such signal QShortcut::activated(QKeySequence)
```

Is there other way than `activated()`? Any help welcomed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are no such signal `activated(QKeySequence)` and you have to connect to the signal `activated()`:

```
 connect(button_1, SIGNAL(activated()), this, SLOT(keybord_shortcuts()));
```

But you can get the real shortcut in a slot by using `sender()`:

```
 void keybord_shortcuts()
 {
      QShortcut* shortcut = qobject_cast<QShortcut*>(sender());
      QKeySequence seq = shortcut->key();
      ...
 }
```